# Xamarin access ListView from the outside

Tags: listview, xamarin

Using Xamarin.Forms with MVVM, I have a ListView of stories with StoryName, StoryCategories and Popup (button). When clicking the Popup button, a popup appears where the user can select different categories for the story. And when the user selects different categories, the StoryCategories label should update with all the selected categories (comma separated). But I'm unable to figure out how to find and update the StoryCategories label from where the popup button was clicked?

I've been developing .net mvc for the last 8 years, and I've always been able to find the answer to my questions here on StackOverflow (thank you!), but for some reason I can't seem to find the answer for this question.

I hope you can help! :)

The popup is a Rg.Plugins.Popup and I'm using the MvvmHelpers from James Montemagno.

Model

```cs
    public class Story : ObservableObject
    {
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
        }

        string categories;
        public string Categories
        {
            get { return categories; }
            set { SetProperty(ref categories, value); }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```cs
public class StoriesViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Story> Stories { get; set; }

        public StoriesViewModel()
        {
            Stories = new ObservableCollection<Story>();

            Stories.Add(new Story { Name = "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", Categories = "a, b" });
            Stories.Add(new Story { Name = "The Restaurant at the End of the Universe", Categories = "b, c, y" });
            Stories.Add(new Story { Name = "Life, the Universe and Everything", Categories = "e" });
            Stories.Add(new Story { Name = "So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish", Categories = "a, c, e" });
        }

        public ICommand OpenPopupCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<Story>((x) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + x.Name);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

View:

```cs
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Stories}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Categories} "/>
                    <Button Text="Click" Command="{ Binding Path=BindingContext.OpenPopupCommand, Source={ x:Reference Stories } }" CommandParameter="{ Binding . }" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: are you asking how your page can know to update when the popup is closed?  You could use MessagingCenter to pass a message from the popup to the page when the popup closes.  Or your popup could expose an event that your page subscribes to.

Comment: @Jason Correct me if I am wrong here but wouldn't passing an `Action` as a constructor parameter and then calling that action from the pop-up page sort of like a callback would be a better approach for this?

Comment: @Jason yes exactly (or preferably to update it as the user selects a category). I will look into MessagingCenter.

Comment: @G.hakim Thank you for the suggestion. Never heard of constructor parameters. I look for some examples :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use clicked event, you could do something like this, I am only guessing the name of the class that you use but you should get it:

```
var story = ((Button)sender).BindingContext as Story;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM pattern, try this:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="Stories">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding StoryName}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding StoryCategories} "/>
                    <Button Command="{ Binding Path=BindingContext.OpenPopupCommand, Source={ x:Reference Stories } }" CommandParameter="{ Binding . }" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the view model

```cs
public ICommand OpenPopupCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command<Story>((x) => 
        {
            // x is Story type
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get an exception: Unhandled Exception: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 14:50. Can not find the object referenced by `Stories` occurred. I've updated the question with my model, viewmodel and view. Maybe I did something wrong? And thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: You removed the name of the list. With your update, the list definition would be `<ListView x:Name="stories" ItemsSource="{Binding Stories}">` (check the x:Name parameter), and then in the command change to `... Source={ x:Reference stories } ...`

Answer (score 0):

The way I have fixed this in the past is by passing the entire story page ViewModel into the pop up page and then when the category is changed you can update the label in the story page from the popup page view model. I do not know if this is the best solution but it does work.